# How to fix "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error while using LuaJIT FFI module in Lua

Tags: caching

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
local os = require("os")

-- Define a structure to represent a cached file with TTL
ffi.cdef[[
    typedef long time_t;
]]

ffi.cdef[[
    typedef struct {
        char* data;
        size_t size;
        time_t timestamp;
    } CachedFile;
]]

-- Create a table to store cached files
local fileCache = {}

-- Function to allocate memory for a CachedFile object
function allocateCachedFile(data, size, timestamp)
    local cachedFile = ffi.new("CachedFile")
    cachedFile.data = ffi.C.malloc(size)
    if cachedFile.data == nil then
        return nil  -- Allocation failed
    end
    ffi.copy(cachedFile.data, data, size)
    cachedFile.size = size
    cachedFile.timestamp = timestamp
    return cachedFile
end

-- Function to free memory used by a CachedFile
function freeCachedFile(cachedFile)
    if cachedFile and cachedFile.data ~= nil then
        ffi.C.free(cachedFile.data)
    end
end

-- Function to load a file into memory and return a CachedFile object
function loadFile(filename, ttlSeconds)
    -- Check if the file is already in the cache
    local cachedFile = fileCache[filename]
    print("cached file:" ..cachedFile)

    if cachedFile and isFileValid(cachedFile) then
        print("File is valid. Accessing cached data.")
        return cachedFile
    else
        print("File not in cache or TTL has expired. Reloading the file.")
        local file = io.open(filename, "rb")
        if not file then
            return nil  -- File not found
        end
        local size = assert(file:seek("end"))
        file:seek("set")
        local data = assert(file:read("*a"))
        file:close()
        local currentTime = os.time()
        cachedFile = allocateCachedFile(data, size, currentTime + ttlSeconds)

        -- If a previous cached file exists, free its memory
        freeCachedFile(fileCache[filename])

        if cachedFile then
            -- Update the cache with the newly loaded file
            fileCache[filename] = cachedFile
        end

        return cachedFile
    end
end

-- Function to check if a CachedFile is still valid based on its TTL
function isFileValid(cachedFile)
    local currentTime = os.time()
    return currentTime <= cachedFile.timestamp
end

-- Example usage:
local file1 = "samplefile"
local ttlSeconds = 300 -- TTL set to 5 minutes

-- Load and cache files
local cachedFile1 = loadFile(file1, ttlSeconds)

-- Access the cached data
if cachedFile1 then
    local data1 = cachedFile1.data
    local size1 = cachedFile1.size
    local dataStr1 = ffi.string(data1, size1)
    print("Data of cachedFile1:\n" .. dataStr1)
    print("Size of cacheFile1:" .. size1 .. " bytes")
else
    print("File not found or TTL expired.")
end
```

For samplefile, added some contents (just one sentence) and while running the code, facing the error like the following

"File not in cache or TTL has expired. Reloading the file.
File not found or TTL expired.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

How to resolve the issue?

Tried multiple debugging but did not work.